# How do I put a for loop into html string content for JavaMailSender?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, string-concatenation

I am sending users order confirmation by mail
This is my order checkout controller:

```
@PostMapping("/purchase")
    public PurchaseResponse placeOrder(@RequestBody Purchase purchase) {

        PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse = checkoutService.placeOrder(purchase);

        sendOrderConfirmationMail(purchase, purchaseResponse);


        return purchaseResponse;
    }


    private void sendOrderConfirmationMail(Purchase purchase, PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse) {

        //List<OrderItem> orderItemList = (List<OrderItem>) purchase.getOrderItems();

        String content="<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "    <h3>WWW.HobbyShop.com</h3>\n" +
                "    <h3>Thank You for your purchase, </h3>" + purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName() + " " + purchase.getCustomer().getLastName() + "\n" +
                "    <h3>Order summary</h3>\n" +



                "    <h3><b>Order Details</b></h3>\n" +
                "    <h5>Your order will ship to:</h5>\n" +
                        purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName() + " " + purchase.getCustomer().getLastName() + ",\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getStreet() + ",\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getCity() + ", " + purchase.getShippingAddress().getState() + " " + purchase.getShippingAddress().getZipCode() + "\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getCountry() + "\n" +
                "    <h5>Your order Tracking Number:</h5>\n" +
                        purchaseResponse.getOrderTrackingNumber() + "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";


        mailService.sendHtmlMail(purchase.getCustomer().getEmail(),"ORDER CONFIRMED",content);
    }
```

I am trying to loop over order item inside the string content like this: see the comment

```
private void sendOrderConfirmationMail(Purchase purchase, PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse) {

        List<OrderItem> orderItemList = (List<OrderItem>) purchase.getOrderItems();

        String content="<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "    <h3>WWW.HobbyShop.com</h3>\n" +
                "    <h3>Thank You for your purchase, </h3>" + purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName() + " " + purchase.getCustomer().getLastName() + "\n" +
                "    <h3>Order summary</h3>\n" +

                
                // displaying order item by looping through the orderItem list
                
                        for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItemList) {
                             orderItem.getName() + "\n" +
                                      "<img src='" + orderItem.getImageUrl() + "'>\n" +
                                      orderItem.getQuantity() + "\n" +
                                      orderItem.getUnitPrice() + "\n" +
     
                          } +
                
                


                "    <h3><b>Order Details</b></h3>\n" +
                "    <h5>Your order will ship to:</h5>\n" +
                        purchase.getCustomer().getFirstName() + " " + purchase.getCustomer().getLastName() + ",\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getStreet() + ",\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getCity() + ", " + purchase.getShippingAddress().getState() + " " + purchase.getShippingAddress().getZipCode() + "\n" +
                        purchase.getShippingAddress().getCountry() + "\n" +
                "    <h5>Your order Tracking Number:</h5>\n" +
                        purchaseResponse.getOrderTrackingNumber() + "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";


        mailService.sendHtmlMail(purchase.getCustomer().getEmail(),"ORDER CONFIRMED",content);
    }
```

But it's giving me error like:

```
';' expected
Expression expected
```

If I remove the for loop the error is gone and it works but I want to loop through the orderItemList to display user order items.

So, How do I add the for loop inside the html string content?

Comment: Don't. Use a templating technology like Thymeleaf or Freemarker for your templates.

Comment: Thank You! Themeleaf  template is great solution.